# In what way does the newly created object of a certain class refer to classes from which it is derived?

Tags: c#

Since every class is derived from the system.object,does the derived class objects refer to the classes in their hierarchy? (classes above them only of course)

for e.g

```
public class A
{
//contains some attributes and methods
}

public class B: A
{
//contains some attributes and methods
}

public class C: B
{
//contains some attributes and methods
}
```

Now does the **OBJECT OF CLASS "C"** refer to A,B as well as the system.object class?

Comment: What do you mean by "refer to"? Object of class C will inherit from class A as well as B.

Comment: see when an object of class c created; then first the object of class system.object is created(as its the highest leveled base class) and a refrence to that object must be send to SOMEWHERE (where does this refrence go??), now the ooject of class A is created, a refrecne to it must be send where somewhere, then following the heirarchy the object of class B created address of this object must be sent finally C class object created, my question here is does all these refrences stored in the object of C?? (reference of all the classes from which C is derived)

Comment: No.. there's only one instance, and it's of class C. That object "is" a "C" - and it's therefore also a B, an A, and a System.Object - because that's part of what it means to be a C.

Comment: To put it another way, the *Class* C refers to *Class* B which refers to *Class* A which refers to *System.Object*. So when you create an *instance* of class C, the instance just needs to "refer" to *Class* C.

Comment: @SanaZehra: If you have a second question, *open another question.*  But, briefly: yes; the base class constructors are called in order from base to derived. (But field initializers are run in order from derived to base.)

Comment: @SanaZehra Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7109564/92414) by Eric Lippert where he links to his blog posts.

Answer (score 6):

It took me a while but I figured it out. **You believe that C# is a "prototype inheritance" language**. It is not.

In a prototype inheritance language, like JavaScript, every object has a reference to its "prototype object". So in JavaScript you might say:

```
function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype.legs = 4;
var rover = new Dog();
var spot = new Dog();
spot.legs = 3; // Poor spot!
print(rover.legs); // 4
print(spot.legs); // 3
```

`rover` and `spot` both have *references* to `Dog.prototype`. When you ask `rover` "how many legs do you have?" `rover` says "I don't know; let me ask my prototype". The object referred to by `rover` itself has a reference to the object referred to by `Dog.prototype`, and that thing has a `legs` property.

When you ask `spot` "how many legs do you have?", `spot` also has a reference to its prototype, but it doesn't need it, because `spot` already knows how many legs it has.

With a little more work we could build a system where the prototype of `Dog.prototype` is the "`Animal` prototype object". And then the chain would continue; `rover` would have a reference to `Dog.prototype`, `Dog.prototype` would have a reference to `Animal.prototype`, and `Animal.prototype` would have a reference to `Object.prototype`.

**C# does not work like that at all.**  In JavaScript, an object is part of a linked list of prototypes and the prototype chain is searched when a property needs to be looked up. In C#, all the information for each property is stored *in every instance*. In C# an object does not refer to an instance of its base types and does not contain an instance of its base types; rather, it *inherits* all of the members of its base types. (Other than constructors and destructors.)

Comment: ok thanks a lot. ur explainations helped me in finding answer to my question!

Comment: @ErricLipert
but still constructors are inherited right? .. as in if i do not provide a zero parameterized constructor in derived class ... base class constructor is called.

Comment: @SanaZehra: Constructors are *not* inherited. If you fail to provide a constructor you get for free a constructor that *calls* the base class constructor, if there is one. You do not *inherit* the base class constructor; you *call* it.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the comments, your misunderstanding seems to be that when you create an instance of class C, there are also separate instances of classes B, A, or Object.  That's not the case.  There is a single object that is an instance of class C, and it may also be treated as an instance of class B, A, or Object (read up on the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).  To modify Eric Lippert's analogy: when a dog is created (born), it is a dog, a mammal, and an animal.  But there's only one dog.

Consider this (Animal, Mammal, Dog, instead of A, B, C):

```
public class Animal 
{ 
    void Breathe();
} 

public class Mammal : Animal
{ 
    void GrowHair();
} 

public class Dog
{ 
    void Bark();
}
```

This inheritance chain gives the following effect:

```
public class C
{
    void Breathe();
    void GrowHair();
    void Bark();
}
```

In terms of fields, and going back to A, B, C, consider this:

```
public class A            
{            
    private int _a;
}            

public class B: A            
{            
    private int _b;
}            

public class C: B            
{            
    private int _c;
}
```

How does an instance of A look in memory?  Some number of bytes of overhead, plus four bytes for `_a`:

```
OVERHEAD
_a : four bytes
```

How does an instance of B look in memory?  It looks just like an instance of A plus four more bytes:

```
OVERHEAD
_a : four bytes
_b : four bytes
```

And an instance of C looks like an instance of A plus eight more bytes:

```
OVERHEAD
_a : four bytes
_b : four bytes
_c : four bytes
```

What's that overhead?  Not surprisingly, **that's the stuff defined by the `Object` class!**  So every time you add another class to the inheritance chain, the fields defined in that class are just tacked onto the end of the memory structure of its parent class.

An instance of a derived class does not *refer to* the data defined by its parent class; it *contains* the data defined by its parent class.

Comment: thank you so muchhhh!!! =) thats what i wanted to know. also when i do not mention any default (zero parameterized) constructor in class "C" then are the default constructors of A,B **as well as  SYSTEM.OBJECT** called when i create an object of "C"? –

Comment: @SanaZehra yes; if you don't specifically call another base class constructor, the base class's default constructor is called.

Comment: @SanaZehra you're most welcome.  Please upvote answers that you find helpful, and accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

An object of type C would also be of type B, A, and `System.Object`.

It will have all the members (public or protected methods, properties, and fields) of the other classes it inherits from. This is why  all objects have a "ToString" method - they inherit it from `System.Object`.

Comment: but does that derived object refer to these classes b,a and system.object? ...i mean does a C  class object contains reference to all of these classes in memory .. ? ..

Comment: @SanaZehra: I think people are confused by your question because it is completely unclear what you mean by "refer to". Suppose you have a bowl of rice. Now I ask you "does your bowl of rice refer to container? And does the rice refer to food?" You would be perfectly justified in asking me to clarify that question. Suppose I asked you "does the phrase 'the White House' refer to the same house as '1600 Pennslyvania Avenue, Washington DC'? That is a much more clear question. It is not at all clear what you mean by "refer to"; try using "refer to" in the "White House" sense.

Comment: It's not stored as 4 separate objects in memory, it's stored as one object (who's definition is a combo of the members of all 4 objects). A Golden Retriever is a Dog, and is also an Animal. When I say "Golden Retriever" I'm not referring to animal, I'm referring to a specific TYPE of animal.

Comment: see when an object of class c created; then first the object of class system.object is created(as its the highest leveled base class) and a refrence to that object must be send to SOMEWHERE (where does this refrence go??), now the ooject of class A is created, a refrecne to it must be send where somewhere, then following the heirarchy the object of class B created address of this object must be sent finally C class object created, my question here is does all these refrences stored in the object of C?? (reference of all the classes from which C is derived)

Comment: @SanaZehra: I think you are not understanding what we mean by "refer to" in the context of an object. Again, suppose you have a piece of paper that says "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" on it. That refers to (1) the White House, (2) a House, (3) an Object. You are asking "The White House is a House and and Object, so where in the White House is the address of the house, and the address of the object?"  There is no such thing; just because the White House is a house and an object does not mean that the White House *contains a reference to a House and a reference to an object*.

Comment: @SanaZehra: Rather, the correct way to think about it is that *a reference to the White House is **also** a reference to a House*. Is that clear?

Comment: @EricLippert: u meant to say that white house is/contains the house .. in OOP terminology .. u mean to say that, 
1)==> the **reference to the base class** is also a **reference to all of its derived classes** ?? meaning that derived and base classes have same references? ...
 2) ==> in the example that i mentioned, an instance of class C contains A,B, and system.object right???

Comment: @SanaZehra: The White House certainly does not *contain* a house. It *is* a house. The White House *is* a house, it *contains* the Oval Office, and "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" *refers to* the same house that "The White House" refers to. You're getting "is", "refers to" and "contains" all mixed up; they are very different.

Comment: @EricLippert:Thank you i got it, by ur answer i which u have discussed prototype inheritance. THANKS A MILLION sir! =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All classes refer to the system.object class implicitly by default.

Comment: but does that derived object refer to these classes b,a and system.object? ...i mean does a C class object contains reference to all of these classes in memory .. ? ..

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but it's more semantics than anything else.

An **object** of class C refers to an **instance** of the class definition named C.  However, it may be type cast into **objects** of type A, B or just plain old System.Object.

There is no "reference" between C and A/B/System.Object.  It's more of an amalgamation of all of those class definitions into a unified "C".

What this means is that you can do the following:

```
function void DoSomething(A input) { 
  // do something as A
}

C myObj = new C();

DoSomething(myObj);
```

In the above case, C will be type cast to an object of type A in the DoSomething call.

You can also do things like:

```
public class A {
  public String MyValue { get; set; }
}

public class B : A{
  public String AnotherValue { get; set; }
}

public class C : B {
  public void DoSomething() {
    MyValue = "Hello";
    AnotherValue = "World";
  }

  public String Output() {
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", MyValue, AnotherValue);

  }
}

C myObj = new C();
C.DoSomething();
String message = C.Output();
// value of message will be "Hello World"
```

Now the reverse is not true.  You *cannot* do the following:

```
function void DoSomething(C input) { 
  // do something as C
}

A myObj = new A();

DoSomething(myObj);
```

In this case you would have a compiler error.